# WebAssembly in the browser security question

Tags: javascript, security, browser, webassembly

Assume I have a web page loaded from `example.com`, with some Javascript and two WebAssemblies from the same origin. I'm attempting to understand the security boundaries, but can't find a reference that puts it all together. So:

- Can either WebAssembly module directly perform HTTP operations on `example.com`? (I think: yes)
- Can the Javascript access any "internal" (data or code) of either WebAssembly that isn't explicitly exported? (I think: no)
- Can WebAssembly 1 access any "internal" (data or code) of WebAssembly 2 that isn't explicity exported? (I think: no)
- Can either WebAssembly access any of the Javascript (data or code)? (I think: no, unless it was a callback or such explicitly registered with it first)

What I'm really trying to get to:

- If WebAssembly 1 contains a "secret token 1", and WebAssembly 2 contains a "secret token 2", is there a way for either of them to gain access to the other's token?

Comment: What does "contains" mean? Compiled into the sourcecode or calculated at runtime?

Comment: I think the answer to all of your questions is yes, depending on the imports / exports of the WASM module.

Comment: @JonasWilms I meant compiled into the source code. But is there a difference? If the exports are made as restrictive as possible, access is still possible you think? Any pointer to a description of this, because I failed to find anything authoritative.

Comment: Yes, there is. A WASM file is just a bunch of text loaded via HTTP. So once WebAssembly1 was able to escape into JS land, it can simply fetch the other source again and perform whatever it wants to do with it. Getting information out of the running runtime is probably more difficult. "as restrictive as possible" can work, but there are a lot of traps in JS (e.g. `eval`) so getting that right is hard.

Answer (score 0):

> If WebAssembly 1 contains a "secret token 1", and WebAssembly 2 contains a "secret token 2", is there a way for either of them to gain access to the other's token?

As they are running in the same origin, possibly yes. But you should be able to prevent this by using distinct origins via sandboxed iframes or similar.